# What is causing my Deferred to fire, having done nothing but add a callback, start the reactor, and connected an endpoint?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using an `if`-statement to decide whether or not to fire a `Deferred`. However it has already fired before the check even runs. From the output, it looks like the `Deferred` is firing immediately upon running `reactor.run()`. Doesn't something have to trigger the callback for this to be happening?

Relevant code snippets:

```
class OutpostBurrowNew(amp.AMP, Protocol):
    protocol = OutpostGopher
    ...
    def rfidTest(self):
        print('Checking for tag - Deferred called: %s' % str(self.defer.called))
        (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            status,uid = self.verify_card()
            cardid = '-'.join([str(x) for x in uid])
            print('Card detected: %s' % str(cardid))
            self.defer.callback()

def main3():
    ''' main3() is for testing reactor usage of RFID-card reading '''
    burrow = OutpostBurrowNew('client')
    burrow.protocol = OutpostGopher
    burrow.connectEndpoint()  # A deferred is created, set on burrow.defer
    def printerCallback(proto):
        # This gets passed the OutpostGopher protocol
        print('main3.printerCallback() - %s ' % str(time.time()))
    burrow.defer.addCallback(printerCallback)
    looper = LoopingCall(burrow.rfidTest)
    loopdefer = looper.start(1, now=False)
    print('Deferred just created, status: %s' % str(burrow.defer.called))
    reactor.run()
```

Output:

```
(env)pi@raspi ~/zenithproject/zenith $ sudo python indev/rfidread_remote.py 
Deferred just created, status: False
Gopher.connectionMade() called.
main3.printerCallback() - 1426884127.26
Checking tag - Deferred called: True
Checking tag - Deferred called: True
Checking tag - Deferred called: True
^CCtrl+C captured, ending read.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that when a Twisted endpoint (in this case a `TCP4ClientEndpoint`) makes a connection to another endpoint (here a `TCP4ServerEndpoint`), the `Deferred` that is created by the connection is immediately fired (i.e. when `Protocol.connectionMade()` is automatically called upon connecting).

This was fixed by not making the connection until the `Deferred` needs to be fired (alternatively, I suppose I could create another `Deferred` to use), like so:

```
class OutpostBurrowNew(amp.AMP, Protocol):
    protocol = OutpostGopher
    #...
    def rfidTest(self):
        #print("Checking tag - Deferred called: %s" % str(self.defer.called))
        print('Tag check')
        (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            # print "Card detected"
            status,uid = self.verifyCard()
            cardid = '-'.join([str(x) for x in uid])
            print('Card detected: %s' % str(cardid))
            #self.defer.callback()
            self.connectEndpoint()

def main3():
    ''' main3() is for testing reactor usage of RFID-card reading '''
    burrow = OutpostBurrowNew('client')
    burrow.protocol = OutpostGopher
    #burrow.connectEndpoint()  # A deferred is created, set on burrow.defer
    looper = LoopingCall(burrow.rfidTest)
    loopdef = looper.start(1, now=False)
    reactor.run()
```

Which results in the following:

```
(env)pi@raspi ~/zenithproject/zenith $ sudo python indev/rfidread_remote.py 
Tag check
Tag check
Card detected: 133-197-223-29-130
Gopher.connectionMade() called.
Tag check
Tag check
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the output:

```py
...
main3.printerCallback() - 1426884127.26
...
```

Going back to your `main`, we see that printerCallback is a callback for `burrow.defer`. We know it's being run, since it's output is printed. So you should find out who's calling it. One way of doing would be to raise an exception in printerCallback, i.e.

```py
def printerCallback(proto):
    print('main3.printerCallback() - %s ' % str(time.time()))
    raise Exception
```

If you need to be more specific with your trace, you can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) module.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to use an `Exception` to see the traceback. That definitely would have led me to the root cause.